# Visual Studio 2017 Pre-Run Build Event

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, webpack, visual-studio-2017

I want to run an npm script every time my project runs. This command will kick off a watch that triggers a webpack hot module swap. It looks like this:

`npm run watch:dev:hmr`

I know I can do this from the post and pre build events, but I do not want to run a watch after every build. I only want to run it before starting a new instance of my project and ideally, stop it when the instance has stopped.

Can this be done?